# Modify a file and save it by the same file name in batch

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to modify a file and save it by the same file name. does this operation is possible in batch?  Indeed by the following example,  "%~f1" is empty at the end of execution while changing it in another name, for example file.txt, it does not empty (working right)

Example:

```
@ echo off

if exist "%~f1" (
findstr /r "I.*=" "%~f1" >"%~f1"
) else (
 echo File does NOT exist!
)
```

Thank for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in that way. The `>` redirection delete the file before `findstr` can process it. Do that this way:

```
@ echo off

if exist "%~f1" (
   findstr /r "I.*=" "%~f1" >"%~f1.tmp"
   move /Y "%~f1.tmp" "%~f1"
) else (
   echo File does NOT exist!
)
```